# how to display context of .cfg file in php?

Tags: php, config

I have a .cfg file which contains some code. I would like to display the whole .cfg in php page. Code for my_config.cfg is here:

```
# ATA/IDE/MFM/RLL support
#
account_name=changl
#
# IDE, ATA and ATAPI Block devices
#
CONFIG_BLK_DEV_IDE=y
CONFIG_BLK_DEV_IDEDISK=y
CONFIG_BLK_DEV_IDECD=n
```

Now I wrote a php code which checks the condition and display what i write in echo. But instead of that I want to display everything from the file. Here is the php code:

```
<?php
$config_file = "my_config.cfg";
$comment = "#";

$fp = fopen($config_file, "r");

while (!feof($fp)) {
  $line = trim(fgets($fp));
  if ($line && !preg_match("/^$comment/", $line)) {
    $pieces = explode("=", $line);
    $option = trim($pieces[0]);
    $value = trim($pieces[1]);
    $config_values[$option] = $value;
  }
}
fclose($fp);

if ($config_values['account_name'] == "changl")
  echo "account_name is changl";
else
  echo "account_name is not changl";
?>
```

The code is working properly. but I want to display the data in the file. Please any help is appreciated.

Comment: How do you want to display it? What have you tried? You have the `$config_values` array, why not just loop that and echo the values?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to use .cfg file in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11316294/how-to-use-cfg-file-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use [`parse_ini_file()`](http://php.net/parse_ini_file):

```
$config_values = parse_ini_file('my_config.cfg');
```

After that you can work with `$config_values` like with any other regular array